# Vertical divider doesn't work in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I opened the Nav example which comes with the standard Bootstrap download (bootstrap-3.0.0\examples\navbar\index.html) and added vertical dividers between two of the links.

However, it doesn't seem to make any difference to the navigation bar:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
<li class="divider-vertical"></li>
<li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
```

Answer (score 108):

I think this will bring it back using 3.0

```
.navbar .divider-vertical {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 9px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}

.navbar-inverse .divider-vertical {
    border-right-color: #222222;
    border-left-color: #111111;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-collapse .nav > .divider-vertical {
        display: none;
     }
}
```

Comment: @Jackson_Sandland Any idea how to make them shorter?

Comment: @carbon_ghost -> I submitted an answer below that works for me - hopefully for you too.

Comment: To make them shorter: Reduce `height` and increase the top & bottom `margin` from 0 so that height + top margin + bottom margin == 50px.

Answer (score 22):

```
.divider-vertical {
height: 50px;
margin: 0 9px;
border-left: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

and now you can use it

```
<ul>
    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

as i also wanted that same thing in a project u can do something like

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
<div class="divider-vertical"></div>
<div class="col-md-5"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.divider-vertical {
    height: 100px;                   /* any height */
    border-left: 1px solid gray;     /* right or left is the same */
    float: left;                     /* so BS grid doesn't break */
    opacity: 0.5;                    /* optional */
    margin: 0 15px;                  /* optional */
}
```

**LESS**

```
.divider-vertical(@h:100, @opa:1, @mar:15) {
    height: unit(@h,px);             /* change it to rem,em,etc.. */
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    float: left;
    opacity: @opa;
    margin: 0 unit(@mar,px);         /* change it to rem,em,etc.. */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some LESS for you, in case you customize the navbar:

```
.navbar .divider-vertical {
    height: floor(@navbar-height - @navbar-margin-bottom);
    margin: floor(@navbar-margin-bottom / 2) 9px;
    border-left: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find using the pipe character with some top and bottom padding works well. Using a div with a border will require more CSS to vertically align it and get the horizontal spacing even with the other elements.

#### CSS

```
.divider-vertical {
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="divider-vertical">&#124;</li>
    <li><a href="#">Faq</a></li>
    <li class="divider-vertical">&#124;</li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li class="divider-vertical">&#124;</li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help also:

```
.navbar .divider-vertical {
    margin-top: 14px;
    height: 24px;
    border-left: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, gray, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
}
```