# Add vertical divider to Yii2's Nav widget

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2, separator

How can I add a vertical divider, that separates top-level items, to Yii2's `Nav`? Is this supported?

From [`Nav`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-nav.html)'s docs I know, that I can add horizontal divider (`'<li class="divider"></li>'`) or horizontal header (`'<li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown Header</li>'`) to first-level dropdown items. But adding these classes at top-level items brings no visual effect.

Is there any way to visually separate let's say `Login` item from all other top-level items in `Nav`?

Comment: How you are trying to add it?

Comment: Apparentlly bootsrap 3 dropped `vertical divider` and you have to code it yourself.

Comment: @arogachev The very same way, as I do for second-level (dropdown) items -- putting string `'<li class="divider"></li>'` instead of array with item configuration. The very same way as it is shown in docs. Only I'm trying to do this for first-level (top-level) items. And it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no vertical divider in bootstrap 3, read more here :

- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9501
- [Vertical divider doesn't work in Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203816/vertical-divider-wont-work-in-bootstrap-3-0)

You should simply create needed css rules.

Answer (score 0):

now you can use `<hr class="dropdown-divider">` to add a vertical line divider for yii2 navbar submenu.

Ex:

```
'items'   => [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/']],
        [
                'label' => 'Settings',
                'items' => [
                    ['label' => 'Schedules', 'url' => ['/schedule/index']],
                    '<hr class="dropdown-divider">',
                    ['label' => 'Procedures', 'url' => ['/procedure/index']]
                ]
        ]
]
```

ref: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar